# Is hardwood flooring safe from termites?

Tags: flooring, hardwood

I have plans to have hardwood flooring in my living room, but I am afraid of termites ruining my flooring.

Comment: As doresoom points out, if you have a termite problem, you'd notice that LONG before your hardwood floors are invaded.

Comment: The direct answer to the question is no, though the monsters are likely to hit softer wood first. Some tropical hardwoods ate inherently insecticidal,  and manufactured lumber might or might not be less attractive than real sins so much of it is adhesives.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a traditional wood framed house, termites in the flooring would be the least of your problems. Structural issues due to termites in load bearing walls would be much worse.

Are you on a slab or crawlspace? If you're on a crawlspace, you already have a wooden subfloor anyway.

Do you have a current termite problem, or are they common in your area? If so, you'll want to have a pest control company come out and do an inspection. Get a quote for remediation if they find any, and ask them if they offer termite bonds. This is essentially insurance against termite infestation in the future. The pest control company will usually come out once or twice a year (for a fee) and either spray termiticide or put out poison bait traps. If they find termite damage while you're paying for the maintenance, they'll cover the cost of remediation.